# Why @testing-library/jest-dom requires ts extensions for import itself?

Tags: javascript, typescript, module, react-testing-library, resolution

According to [this usage](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#with-typescript), when writing `import '@testing-library/jest-dom'`, the defining file extension has to be `ts` in typescript project.

I can see it works, but not understand why the extension must be `ts`. Does an extension affect module resolution? Please help me figure it out.